# Receive emails via broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating an app that has only a single hard coded email address that will receive and respond to questions with the response. Only the body of the email would be necessary. It is being sent back to the app in plain text to be read, bypassing the email client picker.

*My question is this:* Is this even possible to do? I've searched high and low for the solution to this about 3 months now and even Google doesn't know the answer to this one.

Comment: Is *what* possible to do?

Comment: Is it possible to receive the contents of an email message, like the body and have it display or be viewied from within a TextView inside the app? I can send emails all day from my app and I've found tons of documentation on doing that. When it comes to receiving an email, it doesn't seem like anyone knows anything about how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to receive the contents of an email message

You are certainly welcome to write your own POP3 or IMAP4 client, as you could for just about any operating system. You are also certainly welcome to see if there are any fringe email clients for Android that offer an on-device API that offers access to email messages.

Otherwise, no.

> When it comes to receiving an email, it doesn't seem like anyone knows anything about how to do that.

That is because there is nothing much Android-specific about email. Email is not part of the operating system. Email is something provided by apps.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Would this be the reason why you can receive SMS in this manner, being that SMS is part of the OS?

Comment: @gr3yh47: Yes. While SMS client end-user apps are apps, the guts of SMS sending is tightly tied to the GSM or CDMA radio, and so SMS sending and receiving are core OS features. Email, instant messaging, Web browsing, and the like are not part of the core OS, as all they need is an Internet connection, so other than conveniences (e.g., `WebView`) and conventions (e.g., `ACTION_SEND`), the OS doesn't really have much to do with any of that.

Comment: Gotcha. Your mentioning of `WebView` does give me some ideas though. Thanks!