# Receive Emails in Broad Cast Receiver in Android

Tags: android, email, notifications

I want to receive emails in the broad cast receiver, just like we can do it for the sms. I want exact same thing with e mails. Like if someone has a gmail account as his active account and it is connected to android market. So, all the emails he receive on his phone. I want my receiver to read them and get the email address of sender and email body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big No.

There is nothing much Android-specific about email. Email is not part of the operating system. Email is something provided by apps.

Refer : [Receive emails via broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110977/receive-emails-via-broadcast-receiver)